Light Fixture Has Two Hot & Neutral Wires
Not sure what to do here. The light fixture has two hot/black wires and two neutral wires. It was only servicing one light fixture, so I don't know what to do with it. I didn't uninstall it originally so I don't know how it was done with the old light fixture.
Should/can I do one of the following

Bind/tie the 2 black together and white together to make one and connect them to the corresponding wire for the light
Or
Only use one of the black and white wires to connect to the light. And then cap off the other black and white wires not used.
Or....?



You need to figure out where each cable goes and then what each wire does. Two likely scenarios:
Multiple Light Fixtures
If you have multiple light fixtures on a single switch (or a single set of 3-way and possible 4-way switches) then you can have a cable going from the breaker panel to the switch (black hot/white neutral) and then a cable from the switch to the first light fixture (black switched hot/white neutral) and in that light fixture another cable going to the next light fixture. If that's the case then in each light fixture box except the last one, you will have two cables. The blacks go together with a pigtail to the light fixture and the whites go together with a pigtail to the light fixture.
Single Light Fixture with a Switch Loop
Remember: Neutral is always white, white is not always neutral!
This is an older method of wiring, not allowed any more because of the requirement for neutral in most switch boxes. But quite common in the past.
One cable goes from the breaker panel to the light fixture box. It has black hot and white neutral, as usual. However, while the white neutral connects to the light fixture neutral, the hot black connects to the white wire in the switch cable. That white is not neutral. In order to make it clear that it is not neutral, it should be marked with black (or red or any color other than white or green) tape or paint to indicate it is not neutral. Since that means the white wire at the switch is hot (mark it at the switch end as well), the black wire in that cable is the switched hot, which is connected to the light fixture hot.
To do this right:

With all wires separate from each other, turn on the breaker and use a non-contact voltage tester to determine which black wire is hot. Then turn off the breaker.
Connect hot black to the other cable's white. Mark the white with black tape.
Connect the white wire that is paired with the hot black wire to the light fixture neutral.
Connect the remaining black wire to the light fixture hot.

